# Hotlinked images render insanely slow with React and Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, styled-components

I am trying to render images from [Unsplash](http://unsplash.com) using their API.

First, I get some images from their API:

```js
  performSearch = async (query, page) => {
    try {
      const data = await axios.get(
        `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/?page=${page}&per_page=10&query=${query}&client_id=${
          process.env.UNSPLASH_API_KEY
        }`
      )
      const gallery = data.data.results
      this.setState(() => ({
        gallery,
        loadingState: false
      }))
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

This works well and the response is fast. However, when I click one of them to set it as a background somewhere using CSS, it takes forever to load the first time (45 seconds + sometimes). I am using the "regular size", which means that the image is normally between 1 - 3mb. When I load the link in another browser window it loads in milliseconds.

I am thinking that it might have something to do with the fact that the links are not referring directly to an image. Links are in this format, and I need to keep them that way due to Unsplash's hotlinking rules.

regular: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512917987294-2a0f01df2fb8?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI5OTI1fQ&s=cb9f1dfbe5f7a70f89c2e697e76bc40e

Which means that I am trying to render css like:

```
background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512917987294-2a0f01df2fb8?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI5OTI1fQ&s=cb9f1dfbe5f7a70f89c2e697e76bc40e')
```

I am using React 16.4 with Webpack 4.10.2 and Styled Components 3.3 for css.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Because, I have same problem, too.

Comment: Hi, yeah, or at least with a quick-fix: If you specify with and height in the query to Unsplash the problem goes away.